# Trying to bind a list of objects to a WPF datagrid control and seeing blank lines

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I am stuck and need some help. I have spent a full day trying to sort this one out. I have read a lot of examples of how this should be done and it appears that I have done it correctly but clearly I have missed something. I have a blank form with one button and one datagrid. When I click the button I want to load a list of points into the datagrid control. The data must be getting loaded because I see three blank lines in the grid (no headers), but no data. Help please! Thanks!

```
Class MainWindow

Class Point
    Public Inc As String
    Public AZ As String
    Public MD As String
    Public TD As String
End Class


Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    Dim mySurvey As New List(Of Point)
    Dim myPoint1 As New Point
    Dim myPoint2 As New Point

    myPoint1.AZ = "1"
    myPoint1.Inc = "2"
    myPoint1.MD = "100"
    myPoint1.TD = "98"

    myPoint2.AZ = "10"
    myPoint2.Inc = "20"
    myPoint2.MD = "1000"
    Point2.TD = "980"


    mySurvey.Add(myPoint1)
    mySurvey.Add(myPoint2)
    dgSurvey.ItemsSource = mySurvey

End Sub
```

End Class

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="45,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="57" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgSurvey" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="172" Width="275"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: can you share your xaml ?

Comment: Just added it to the question. Thanks nit

Comment: I think you should define properties in your `Point` class, not public fields, for this to work.

Comment: icebat you are awesome. Thanks so much. Problem solved. Post as an answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For binding to work you should define **properties** in your `Point` class, not public fields.
This is explicitly stated in [MSDN: Binding Sources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The properties you use as binding source properties for a binding must be public
>   properties of your class. Explicitly defined interface properties cannot be 
>   accessed for binding purposes, nor can protected, private, internal, 
>   or virtual properties that have no base implementation.
>
> You cannot bind to public fields.